# how to start massive concurrent client on the same machine

Tags: multithreading, sockets, concurrency, operating-system

I run a daytime server on my own computer, it's a mac air laptop.

I want to test it's capability of concurrency. So I want to start massive concurrent client connecting to the daytime server. But what I come across is

- a process can not start too many threads, it's limit is about 2000 threads per process, out out memory limitation.
- I can not start too many process, since socket descriptor is limited ...

Therefore, how can I do the concurrency test, on the condition I do not have many other computers ...

Answer (score 1):

You don't need many threads to have many connections. You don't need many processes to have many connections. It sounds like your real question is "how can I write a program that can handle large numbers of connections". On a Mac, the answer is [kqueue](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man2/kqueue.2.html). You can also use the [Boost ASIO](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/doc/html/boost_asio.html) library which will call `kqueue` for you and gives you a nicer interface.

Comment: Thanks @David, you point out my ultimate target, yes, I'd like to program an effective concurrency server. I was told this is a well-known topic, the so-called 10k problem. However, I am just a rookie now to network programming, therefore I'd like to feel a single computer's capability. So, I write a simple concurrent server and want to simulate massive simultaneous connection. How many clients could the server deal with without those special techniques. In short, even if I already made the desired massive throughput server, how could I prove its ability in test phase?

Comment: You would have to use a massive throughput test client, probably written by someone very familiar with high throughput coding.